# how to render object array in react?

Tags: reactjs

here is my componentDidmount

```
componentDidMount() {
    for ( var i in course ) {
        let title = course[i];
        const ref = firestore.collection('courses');
        ref.where("class", "array-contains", course[i]).get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const count = querySnapshot.size
                course_stats.push({
                    title: title,
                    value: count,
                });
            });
    }

    console.log(course_stats)
    this.setState({
        courses: course_stats,
    })
  }
```

here is my render

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props; 
if (this.state.courses) {
    console.log(this.state.courses)
    return (
        <ul>
            {course_stats.map(d => <li key={d.title}>{d.title}</li>)}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

on the line console.log, I can see the object array in that. However, when i try render that, it doesn't show anything.
[this is the console.log capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nITce.png)

how can I render the title and value of array?
Thank you!

Comment: I just figured out that it rendered, but I should click the page twice to render.

Comment: is it because you're mapping `course_stats` instead of `this.state.courses`?

Comment: after i change to this.state.courses, i need to access the same page twice to render.

Comment: Then it is because you're using a promise to load your `courses` as data into your app. The for loop will execute, but the `.then` won't resolve until later. By the time all your data is loaded `this.setState` has already executed with no courses. To fix this you have to call `this.setState` after all your data is loaded, perhaps as a callback to `Promise.all` or by using `async/await`

Comment: One quick but inefficient fix would be to add `this.setState({courses: course_stats })` after the `course_stats.push()` call in your for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to izb's answer, `this.setState` has already executed, so you should use async/await, or add a seperate callback function like this that returns a Promise

```
setAsync(state) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.setState(state, resolve)
  });
}

handleChange = (event) => {
  return this.setAsync({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
}
```